# Silverlight/WPF Many to Many List of Checkboxes Binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight, entity-framework, data-binding, many-to-many

I have an entities model with a many to many relationship. For simiplicity, lets assume its a car entity and a feature(cd player, moonroof, etc.) entity.

I have a Silverlight/WPF form in which you edit the car entity. I would like to have the list of possible features (everything in the features table) be a list of checkboxes.  That part is easy. However, I am trying to think of an elegant way to bind the checkboxes so that when I check, uncheck one of them, it add/removes the association between that feature and car.

I know that this can easily be done with good old WinForms-style event handlers, but I would like to know if anybody has a way of doing this using data binding so that I can still keep my presentation and my logic separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) presentation pattern?

I would suggest creating a ViewModel class to bind to. This class could contain properties like `HasSunroof` for the checkboxes to bind to. In the set methods of these properties they could alter the related property (like the `Sunroof` property).

An alternative would be to use an `IValueConverter`. Bind to the actual property (say `Sunroof`). In the converter, return true (checked) if the value of `Sunroof` is not equal to null, otherwise return false. The `ConvertBack`() function could turn the case where IsChecked is equal to true into the required object for the property.